# Using HTML / Hyperlinks with CTaskDialog SetContent / SetFooterText

Tags: mfc, taskdialog

With `SetFooterText` you can provide a **hyperlink** using HTML syntax and it is displayed visually as a link. However, I find that only a **website** link works here. If I use a `mailto` link it won't work. Is there a workaround?

Also, if I try to use basic HTML, like wrapping a word with bold tags using `SetContent` it just shows as literal text.

What HTML syntax is supported by `CTaskDialog`? Can we easily override?

Comment: It works for me `"<a href=\"mailto:x@y.com\">link</a>"` Please explain in more detail, or maybe you don't have a default email program on your system.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani How odd! Now the `mailto` bit is working. Hhm! One sorted!

Comment: [Win32 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Commctrl/ns-commctrl-_taskdialogconfig) state, that only the `<a>` tag is supported.

Comment: @zett42 OK, thanks for the confirmation. Would have been the icing on the cake but not to worry.